# Replace own Logger with SLF4J and Logback - Refactor help needed

Tags: java, logging, refactoring, slf4j

I'm refactoring some legacy code that has it's own Logger implementation. This should be replaced by the SLF4J Logger (with Logback binding).

```
package com.own.log;
public class Logger{
    public static void write(String message) {
        ... write to file ...
    }
}
```

All business code contains hundreds of loggers like:

```
Logger.write("message for my logfile");
```

What is the best approach to refactor the old code to use the new logger?

```
org.slf4j.Logger logger = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(Business.class);
logger.debug("message for my logfile");
```

Comment: Depends heavily on how much effort you're allowed to put into this. You could go and replace every usage with a slf4j - call, which would be quite expensive. With an automatted replace feasable, I think. Or you change the write method to forward the message to slf4j/logback. That would be cheap. It wouldn't be much of a benefit, too though.